# variadic template argument for std::function

Tags: c++11, variadic-templates

Recently, I've been working on a little project alongside my c++ game-dev engine : it's a programming language, written in C++, in one header, named kickC. Here is what I have done so far : (See question below)

```
#ifndef KICK_C_INCLUDED_H
#define KICK_C_INCLUDED_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <exception>
#include <functional>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#define LOG(x) std::cout << x << std::endl;

namespace strutil
{
    inline unsigned CountWords(const std::string& value){
        std::string temp = value;
        std::replace_if(temp.begin(), temp.end(), std::ptr_fun<int, int>(std::isspace), ' ');
        temp.erase(0, temp.find_first_not_of(" "));
        if(temp.empty())
            return 0;
        return std::count(temp.begin(), std::unique(temp.begin(), temp.end()), ' ') + !std::isspace(*value.rbegin());
    }
}

class KickCException : std::exception
{
public:
    explicit KickCException(const char* msg, bool fatal = false)
        :   msg_(msg){}
    explicit KickCException(const std::string& msg)
        : msg_(msg){}
    virtual ~KickCException() throw(){}
    virtual const char* what() const throw(){
        return std::string("[error :] [")
            .append(msg_)
            .append("]")
            .c_str();
    }
protected:
    std::string msg_;

};
class KickCFileException : KickCException
{
public:
    explicit KickCFileException(const char* msg)
        : KickCException(msg){}
    explicit KickCFileException(const std::string& msg)
        : KickCException(msg){}
    virtual ~KickCFileException() throw(){}
    const char* what() const throw() override{
        return std::string("[file error :] [")
            .append(msg_)
            .append("]")
            .c_str();
    }
};
class KickCEmptyStringException : KickCException
{
public:
    explicit KickCEmptyStringException(const char* msg)
        : KickCException(msg){}
    explicit KickCEmptyStringException(const std::string& msg)
        : KickCException(msg){}
    virtual ~KickCEmptyStringException() throw(){}
    const char* what() const throw() override{
        return std::string("[empty string error :] [")
            .append(msg_)
            .append("]")
            .c_str();
    }
};


class KickCAPIBehaviourImplementation
{
public:
    KickCAPIBehaviourImplementation(){}
    ~KickCAPIBehaviourImplementation(){}

    void AddDefined(const std::string& str, std::function<void(void)> func){
        m_values[str] = func;
    }
    void ParseAndApplyLine(const std::string& line){
        std::istringstream iss(line);

        for(unsigned i = 0; i < strutil::CountWords(line); ++i){
            static std::string word = "";
            iss >> word;
            for(auto it_map = m_values.begin(); it_map != m_values.end(); ++it_map){
                if(it_map->first == word)
                {
                    (it_map->second)(/*HERE ! GIVE SOME ARGUMENTS ! */);
                }
            }
        }
    }
private:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<void(void)>> ///so far, args is void... m_values;
};

#endif //KICK_C_INCLUDED_H
```

///src

```
int main(int argc, const char** args){
    std::ifstream file("script.kick");
    KickCAPIBehaviourImplementation kickCApiBehaviour;
    try{
        if(!file.is_open())
            throw KickCFileException("unvalid fileName taken at input");
        kickCApiBehaviour.AddDefined("print", [&](void){std::cout << "print found !" << std::endl;});
        while(!file.eof()){
            std::string line;
            std::getline(file, line);
            kickCApiBehaviour.ParseAndApplyLine(line);
        }
    }catch(KickCException& e){
        LOG(e.what());
    }
    file.close();
  std::cin.get();
}
```

So here is the Question :  I would like to pass std::function (see class `KickCAPIBehaviourImplementation` ) a variable argument of **types** : I need to use variatic templates, of course, but the question how can I implement it so i end up calling my functions like this ?

```
kickCApiBehaviour.AddDefined("print", [&](int arg1, char * arg2, int arg3){std::cout << arg1 << arg2 << arg3 << std::endl;});
```

Comment: You could use  std::function<void(ARGS...)> but the problem is that all of your `std::function` which are added to the same class must have the same number and type of arguments. Is that what you want ?

Comment: you could use a `std::vector<const char *> &args` ?

Comment: how ? Can you show me an example ?

Comment: If the function is `std::function<void(const std::vector<const char*>&)>` then it can be passed a vector containing zero or more strings.

Comment: thank you : i  got it now  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the parser into the `std::function`.

Where you add the function, include a signature:

```
// helper type:
template<class T>struct tag{using type=T;};

kickCApiBehaviour.AddDefined(
  "print", // the name
  tag<void(int,char*,int)>{}, // the signature
  [&](int arg1, char * arg2, int arg3){
    std::cout << arg1 << arg2 << arg3 << std::endl;
  } // the operation
);
```

store a `std::function< error_code(ParserState*) >`.  Inside `AddDefined`, store a lambda that includes a call to the code that parses arguments and calls the passed in lambda:

```
template<class R, class...Args, class F>
void AddDefined(std::string name, tag<R(Args...)>, F f) {
  std::function< error_code(ParserState*) > r =
    [f](ParserState* self)->error_code {
      // here, parse each of Args... out of `self`
      // then call `f`.  Store its return value,
      // back in `self`.  If there is a parse error (argument mismatch, etc),
      // return an error code, otherwise return no_error
    };
  m_values[name] = r;
};
```

then `m_values` contains the operation "take a parser state, and parse the arguments, and call the function in question on them".

Comment: Just a question : how do I call the function in `ParseAndApplyLine()` ?

Comment: @matt you have stores it in a map from name to `std::function`, no?  Invoke it from the map.  Feed it whatever it needs to parse the arguments (a pointer to a parser, a string, a stream, whatever).  The point is that it is inside the std function that you have your arg parsing code.  It may need to return more than just an error code (for ex, how many characters it consumed) if you do not abstract it.